# What are the steps to solve this limit $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{4x^2 - 4}{x-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm reviewing for a quiz but this one has got me stumped.  I know the answer is $8$, but I'm confused about how to get there.

What is $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{4x^2 - 4}{x-1}?$$
I know when you plug in $1$ you get $\frac 0 0$, so there is more work to be done, but I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Factor the numerator, then cancel what you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Here you need only *factor the numerator,* then *cancel* the common factor in the numerator and denominator, and evaluate the limit of the resulting function as $x \to 1$.

$$\frac{4x^2-4}{x-1}=\frac{4(x^2-1)}{x-1}=\frac{4\cancel{(x-1})(x+1)}{\cancel{x-1}}=\;\;4(x+1) \;\;\;\text{when}\;x \neq 1$$

Now, evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 1} 4(x + 1)$$

Recall, when we find the limit of a function $f(x)$ as $x \to a$, $f(x)$ might not be defined *at* $x = a$. But with functions like this, the limit as $x$ *approaches* $a$ nonetheless exists, and with limits, we are interested in what happens very near $a$, not what happens precisely *at* $x = a$.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{4x^2-4}{x-1}=\frac{4(x^2-1)}{x-1}=\frac{4(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=4(x+1)\text{  if }x-1\ne0$$

If $x\to1,x\ne1\implies x-1\ne0$

Comment: @kb95825, To solve tougher limits unlike this one, see l'Hospital's rule  (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)